# changing the retryprompt at runtime in promptoptions

Tags: c#-4.0, botframework, azure-bot-service

I want to change the retryprompt at runtime in promptoptions? The requirement is change the wording at runtime based on input given by user. Is it possible. Is there any way to send image in the dialog. I want to send image instead of text in promptoptions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are trying for retryprompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the virtual assistant sample in which the same is implemented. The DefaultAdapter in the Virtual Assistant template provides a set of Middlewares out of the box including the following:

Show Typing Middleware - Sends typing indicators from the bot.

https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/handbook/activity-flow/